# Difference between 'grep' in Ubuntu and Kali Linux?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I always used the following command to filter out my contacts email addresses from a directory in Kali Linux:

```
grep -rIhEo "\b[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\b" >> 1A
```

I tried it in Ubuntu now and its not working. There is no error message, just its doing something but without result and end. Why?

I tried with Ubuntu 12.04 and Xubuntu 12.04.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe it's because Ubuntu's default shell is `dash`, whereas Kali Linux uses `chsh` as default shell. [Source](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/11/27/how-to-add-remove-user-standard-user-non-root-in-kali-linux/)

Comment: I changed the shell now to /bin/bash. The problem remains.

Comment: What's the input you're testing this with?

Comment: @Ploutox Ubuntu ships with `bash` as default, I'm pretty sure. Also, I don't think it matters anyway, since `grep` isn't a bash builtin, but a separate binary in its own right.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with your locale settings? See if this makes a difference if you use `[[:alnum:]._-]` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]`

Comment: @Scrutinizer I always thought the latter was more portable, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Sparhawk Unless you control the locale, classic range expressions are no longer reliable and POSIX character classes are preferable. Only pre-POSIX utilities do not understand them.

Comment: @Oli I tested it with different inputs. For example with just a file containing 2 contact mail addresses.

Comment: @Scrutinizer Still the same. It makes no difference here.

Comment: Could you post a sample of a file for which it is not working with anonymized email addresses?

Comment: @Scrutinizer Sure. The only content of the only one file is: example@example.com. The cursor is blinking, no error message but nothing happens.

Comment: So what happens if you do `echo example@example.com. | grep -rIhEo "\b[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\b"`

Comment: @Scrutinizer It gives the example email address correct back. No problems here.

Comment: Yet the file `1A` is empty? What happens when you `echo example@example.com. > test.file; grep -rIhEo "\b[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\b" test.file`

Comment: @Scrutinizer Yes, 1A is still empty. Now it gives example@example.com back and writes example@example.com to the new file test.file. Just with a dot at the end of the line in the file.

Comment: So if it works with `test.file` the question remains, why does it not work with the other file? Could you try again with that other file. If it still does not work, then maybe there are special characters in there  ? You could check with `od -c < file`

Comment: That's also not working: `grep -rIhEo "\b[[:alnum:]._-]+@[[:alnum:]._-]+\.[[:alnum:]._-]+\b"
` I don't think that it has to do something with the empty file. Its about the search for the string with grep I guess.

Comment: What empty file? Anyway, grep appears to function well so it must be something with the file or how you specify the file(s) as input..... 
Wait a minute. In your example, you are not specifying any file(s) as input ! There is only are redirect to append the output to the file "1A"

Comment: @Scrutinizer Exactly. With `grep -rIhEo` I search the directory I am in recursive for every file containing the given string. And that is what's not working. In Kali Linux it works well exactly the same way.

Comment: You would still need to specify the directory for example with a `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify files as input to the grep command:

```
grep -rIhEo "\b[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\b" file(s) >> 1A
```

Or specify files with a wildcard or use the current directory.

```
grep -rIhEo "\b[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\b" . >> 1A
```

---

```
GREP(1)                                                                GREP(1)

NAME
       grep, egrep, fgrep - print lines matching a pattern

SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
       grep [OPTIONS] [-e PATTERN | -f FILE] [FILE...]
```

Comment: You got it. Thanks so much for your persistent help! So in Ubuntu standard shell you need to specify the directory, in Kali Linux standard shell it takes the current directory if no is specified.

Comment: @DataDriven . You are welcome, glad you found it..

Comment: @DataDriven That's really interesting though. I wonder if Kali Linux would attempt to use `.` if there is an error? That seems quite strange. (I presume this difference is from the shell and not grep.)